# Binance Smart chain - private network implementation - guideline required

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-stake, binance

I am trying to understand the way Binance proof of stake authority(PoSA) works by implementing a private local blockchain. Therefore, I tried their official documentation but it seems like they simply created multiple nodes by using proof of authority (PoA). I could not distinguish what is the difference between the classical ethereum PoA and Binance PoSA.
Please help to get a proper working guideline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't know that Binance is POS, who told u that. As war I know, it is only copy of ethereum with poa instesd

Comment: Thanks, Proof of stake authority actually. Do you know any platform where I could use POS?

Answer (score 1):

From the Binance [docs](https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/a-quick-guide-to-bnb-staking-on-binance-smart-chain-bsc):

> Binance Smart Chain uses a consensus model called **Proof of Staked
> Authority (PoSA)**. It’s a hybrid between Proof of Authority (PoA) and
> Delegated Proof of Stake (DPoS). This consensus model can support a
> short block time and low fees, and it only requires 21 validators to
> run.

To become a validator you must *"Stake at least 10,000 BNB."* In today's prices, that's $6.3 million.

However, [elsewhere](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/guides/concepts/consensus.html) in the docs it says:

> The implement of the consensus engine is named as Parlia which is
> similar to clique.

So it appears to be PoA but with slashing conditions included.

The main part of the Parlia implementation is in [`parlia.go`](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/blob/master/consensus/parlia/parlia.go).

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for clarifying the actual algorithm it does works. Similar to creating local nodes by using geth and rpc, I wanted to created a local blockchain for my lab. The main aims for me is to use a platform that is based on proof of stake. I come to know that Ethereum 2.0 suppose to have PoS, but I believe it is not released yet. Could you please advice any?